# Created/Modify columns don't appear when creating view

Tags: document-library, list-view, column

I have a SharePoint 2010 instance and am trying to create a view for a document library.

I want to include the Created and Modified columns so I can do some filtering on dates, however neither the Created or Modified date columns are visible in the column list.

This document library, as far as I can tell, is identical to another that does have these columns.

Is there any reason for the columns missing in this library specifically?

Answer (score 3):

Can you see your columns and can be checked as visible in "Edit view" page? 
If no and if it's for one library only, maybe this links can helps you

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/1e307b08-7c15-4b4d-ab25-eed3b273cd95

http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/document-library-modified-column-missing-for-sorting-after-using-content-and-structure-and-subfolder-renaming-changes-modified-column/

Comment: I don't really have access to do any code changes, and creating a new library is not really an option as we'll loose the version history of the documents.

Comment: Your documents can be moved with version history, if target library has the same fields and versioning is turned on. For example via Content & Structure (I think that this item in Site Settings in for Publishing pages only), you can move them (drag & drop in explorer view) or transfer them using some 3rd party application (CopyMove, DocAve, ControlPoint... Your SP Admins may have something that you can use).